# What does the prototype "const int* foo(int)" mean,especially in contrast to "int* foo(int)"?I understand the second only

Tags: c, pointers, constants, prototype

I know that `int* foo(int)` prototype means that `foo` is a function that takes an integer argument and returns a pointer to an integer.But what does the following mean?

```
  const int* foo(int);
```

I tried to reason but failed.My book doesn't say anything about this but I see stuff like this  in library function prototypes.So please tell me what it means.

Comment: When in doubt [cdecl](http://cdecl.org/)

Comment: 1. You haven't googled `const keyword C`, have you? 2. http://cdecl.org

Comment: The same, except that you aren't allowed to change what `foo`'s result points to.

Comment: I was just searching for cdecl :)

Comment: do you have any counter question, I believe links provided to are sufficient, let me know you have other doubts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So that value pointed by returned address can't be change via address (useful when foo() returns address of const).

```
const int* p2c =  foo(int);
*p2c=10;  <-- "error"
```

Comment: Not quite true--You _can_ change the returned value (the pointer) -- you just can't change what it points to.

Answer (score 1):

from [cdecl](http://www.cdecl.org/):

this means

> declare foo as function (int) returning pointer to const int

Answer (score 1):

```
const int* foo(int);
```

foo is a function that takes an integer argument and returns a pointer to an const integer.It means you are allowed to change pointer but not it's value.